# javax.naming.NameNotFoundException: Name [jdbc/FsEDBUser] is not bound in this Context

Tags: java, tomcat, jdbc, tomcat8

I've set up JNDI resources before, but I'm coming across an issue I'm not sure how to correct on my `apache-tomcat-8.0.36` server.

My `context.xml` file contains the following:

```
<ResourceLink name="jdbc/FsEDBAdmin" global="jdbc/FsEDBAdmin" type="javax.sql.DataSource" />
<ResourceLink name="jdbc/FsEDBUser" global="jdbc/FsEDBUser" type="javax.sql.DataSource" />
<Resource name="jdbc/FsEDBAdmin" auth="Container"
          type="javax.sql.DataSource" driverClassName="org.postgresql.Driver"
          url="jdbc:postgresql://location"
          username="user_admin" password="pass"
          maxActive="20" maxIdle="10" maxWait="-1"/>

<Resource name="jdbc/FsEDBUser" auth="Container"
          type="javax.sql.DataSource" driverClassName="org.postgresql.Driver"
          url="jdbc:postgresql://location"
          username="user_user" password="pass"
          maxActive="20" maxIdle="10" maxWait="-1"/>
```

My `web.xml` :

```
<resource-ref>
    <description>Admin Connection</description>
    <res-ref-name>jdbc/FsEDBAdmin</res-ref-name>
    <res-type>javax.sql.DataSource</res-type>
    <res-auth>Container</res-auth>
</resource-ref>
<resource-ref>
    <description>User Connection</description>
    <res-ref-name>jdbc/FsEDBUser</res-ref-name>
    <res-type>javax.sql.DataSource</res-type>
    <res-auth>Container</res-auth>
</resource-ref>
```

I'm also using these connections to define a `Realm` for authentication:
`server.xml`:

```
<Realm className="org.apache.catalina.realm.LockOutRealm">
    <!-- This Realm uses the UserDatabase configured in the global JNDI
         resources under the key "UserDatabase".  Any edits
         that are performed against this UserDatabase are immediately
         available for use by the Realm.  -->
    <Realm className="org.apache.catalina.realm.UserDatabaseRealm"
           resourceName="UserDatabase"/>
    <Realm className="org.apache.catalina.realm.DataSourceRealm"
        digest="digest_method" dataSourceName="jdbc/FsEDBAdmin" userTable="schema.table_name"
        userNameCol="name_col" userCredCol="pass_col"
        userRoleTable="schema.table_name" roleNameCol="rolename_col"
        localDataSource="true"/>
  </Realm>
```

But when I launch my application I'm getting the error mentioned in the title.  I can give a full stack trace if requested.

I'd like to add on, that this was working at one point and the most recent change was the use of the `Realm` for authentication.  Obviously I've made a mistake in defining these resources in one location or another, so another set of eyes to tell me where would be greatly appreciated.  Thank you.

EDIT:  This is how I'm calling the resource:

```
import path.to.CommonTools;
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import javax.naming.Context;
import javax.naming.InitialContext;
import javax.naming.NamingException;
import org.apache.tomcat.dbcp.dbcp2.BasicDataSource;

/**
 *
 * @author Michael Potts
 */
public enum Resource {
    INSTANCE;

private static BasicDataSource basicAdmin = null;
private static BasicDataSource basicUser = null;
private static final String JNDI_PREFIX = "java:/comp/env";
private static final String ADMIN_DB_NAME = "jdbc/FsEDBAdmin";
private static final String USER_DB_NAME = "jdbc/FsEDBUser";

/**
 * Secure method that gives a connection from the pool for an Admin user
 * @return java.sql.Connection
 * @throws Exception Throws if Context isn't properly defined on Server 
 */
public static Connection getAdminConnection() throws Exception {
    try {
        if(basicAdmin == null) { //1st time load
            Context dbContext = (Context) new InitialContext().lookup(JNDI_PREFIX);
            basicAdmin = (BasicDataSource) dbContext.lookup(ADMIN_DB_NAME);
        }
        return basicAdmin.getConnection();
    } catch (NamingException | SQLException e) {
        throw new RuntimeException("\nInvalid JNDI resource: " + ADMIN_DB_NAME + CommonTools.getStackTrace(e));
    }
}

/**
 * Secure method that gives a connection from the pool for a standard user
 * @return java.sql.Connection
 * @throws Exception Throws if Context isn't properly defined on Server 
 */
public static Connection getUserConnection() throws Exception {
    try {
        if(basicUser == null) { //1st time load
            Context dbContext = (Context) new InitialContext().lookup(JNDI_PREFIX);
            basicUser = (BasicDataSource) dbContext.lookup(USER_DB_NAME);
        }
        return basicUser.getConnection();
    } catch (NamingException | SQLException e) {
        throw new RuntimeException("\nInvalid JNDI resource: " + USER_DB_NAME + CommonTools.getStackTrace(e));
    }
}
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So the solution for me was to remove ALL ENTRIES except the base `Resource` definitions in `context.xml`.  This includes removing `ResourceLink` entries.  So if you've tried everything and you're getting this error like I am just ignore all documentation and just define in Context.xml.